# Excel VBA runtime error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro to paste special formulas but keep getting a runtime error 1004 "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed".

This macro comes directly from using the "Record Macro" provided by Excel.

```
Sub paste_formulas()
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
         SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Here is the sequence of events:

1. Manually select a range of cells in CSV file A and copy (CTRL+C).
2. Switch to the XLS file B and select the cell were I want the copied data pasted.
3. Press Macros and run personal.xlsm!paste_formulas

That's when I get the error. Why does this work manually when I copy/paste-special formulas, but fail in the macro?

Note: I need this to work in the above sequence regardless of the selected range that I copy (will vary from time to time), and regardless of the location I paste formulas to (will also vary from time to time). In other words, hardcoding a fixed range for copy and/or paste won't work for me.

Thanks in advance for any help understanding why my code isn't working or providing a work-around.

Comment: The only way I see this error pops up is because you lost the source i.e. the dotted line created around the source data when you did "Ctrl+C" disappeared (could be by pressing Esc or else) before you executed the macro.  Hence, nothing to paste ==> Runtime error 1004.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is very simple, When you copy from the CSV and then in your workbook, click on `Macros` in the Developer Toolbar, Excel clears the clipboard.

Excel has this habit of clearing the clipboard when you click on `Developer | Macros`. To demonstrate this, copy the cells from the same workbook. You will see the ant like border around the cells. Now in the same workbook, click on Developer | Macros. The Ant like borders will disappear :)

[image]

Set a shortcut key for your macro and use that. it will work :)

[image]

Comment: This also answers the question "How do I set a short-cut key for a macro after I wrote it?"