# Paste Special error in VBA Excel 2010

Tags: excel, paste, vba

I am trying to copy and paste values, which is actually no difficult task.

In order to only copy the values of the cells values I use Paste.Special x1PasteValues.

Here comes the funny part:

```
Set wsd = Sheets("Data")
wsd.Select
With wsd
.Range("L5:X5").Select

.PasteSpecial x1=PasteValues        <~~ Runtime error: 1004        
'.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues <~~ equivalent to the above
'.PasteSpecial                      <~~ This works, but only pastes the formula
'.Paste                             <~~ This pastes the formula

End With
```

If I execute the code I receive a runtime error: 1004 and I can't find a solution for it. The same happens if I want to paste the format.

Maybe the problem is that the macro is written in an ActiveX button, which is why I have to use with wsd.

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

edit: I just found a similar topic in which a problem occured by switching a workbook and manually activating a macro (instead of i.e. a macro button). Could the same problem occur in my code, since I switch between worksheets?

[Excel VBA runtime error 1004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680758/excel-vba-runtime-error-1004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are referencing the sheet, selecting the cells, but then referencing the sheet object again to paste into without giving a range to do so. This works on Excel 2013, you may need to play with the syntax on other versions

```
Set wsd = Sheets("Data")
With wsd
    .Range("L5:X5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False
End With
```

Comment: Thank you sir or mam! :)